# Dimensioning line with QAD plugin

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I would like to use QAD plugin to emulate AutoCAD, especially to draw some dimensioning. There are two possibilities to do so: click on 2 points or select an object.

I want to use the object selection on a line with more than 2 vertices, I would like something like that, but with the actual length of the line (currently the length is the one between the start and end points of the line, and I did it manually with the first method) : [image]

And when I try to use the object selection, I get a result limited by the only two vertices of the section I clicked, as such (I clicked on the almost horizontal section):
[image]

Would someone know how I could proceed to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Use the option "click on 2 points" using osnap.